# React TransitionGroup and React.cloneElement do not send updated props

Tags: reactjs, animation, redux, react-router, reactcsstransitiongroup

I am following Chang Wang's tutorial for making reusable React transitions with HOCs and `ReactTransitionGroup`([Part 1](https://medium.com/@cheapsteak/animations-with-reacttransitiongroup-4972ad7da286#.9d0ond1lo) [Part 2](https://medium.com/@cheapsteak/reusing-reacttransitiongroup-animations-with-higher-order-components-1e7043451f91#.jxwmzf8l7)) in conjunction with Huan Ji's tutorial on page transitions ([Link](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/react-page-transition-animations-9d18c90a9831#.ielm852rq)).

The problem I am facing is that `React.cloneElement`does not seem to be passing updated props into one of its children, while other children do properly receive updated props.

### **First, some code:**

**TransitionContainer.js**

`TransitionContainer` is a container component that is akin to `App` in Huan Ji's tutorial. It injects a slice of the state to it's children.

The children of the `TransitionGroup` are all an instance of an HOC called `Transition` (code further down)

```
import React from 'react';
import TransitionGroup from 'react-addons-transition-group';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
class TransitionContainer extends React.Component{
  render(){
    console.log(this.props.transitionState);
    console.log("transitionContainer");
    return(
      <div>
      <TransitionGroup>
      {
        React.Children.map(this.props.children,
         (child) => React.cloneElement(child,      //These children are all instances of the Transition HOC
           { key: child.props.route.path + "//" + child.type.displayName,
             dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
             transitionState: this.props.transitionState
           }
         )
        )
      }

      </TransitionGroup>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default connect((state)=>({transitionState:state.transitions}),(dispatch)=>({dispatch:dispatch}))(TransitionContainer)
```

**Transition.js**

`Transition` is akin to Chang Wang's HOC. It takes some options, defines the `componentWillEnter` + `componentWillLeave` hooks, and wraps a component. `TransitionContainer` (above) injects `props.transitionState` into this HOC. However, sometimes the props do not update even if state changes (see **The Problem** below)

```
import React from 'react';
import getDisplayName from 'react-display-name';
import merge from 'lodash/merge'
import classnames from 'classnames'
import * as actions from './actions/transitions'
export function transition(WrappedComponent, options) {
  return class Transition extends React.Component {
    static displayName = `Transition(${getDisplayName(WrappedComponent)})`;
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          willLeave:false,
          willEnter:false,
          key: options.key
      };
    }
    componentWillMount(){
      this.props.dispatch(actions.registerComponent(this.state.key))
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
      this.props.dispatch(actions.destroyComponent(this.state.key))
    }
    resetState(){
      this.setState(merge(this.state,{
        willLeave: false,
        willEnter: false
      }));
    }
    doTransition(callback,optionSlice,willLeave,willEnter){
      let {transitionState,dispatch} = this.props;
      if(optionSlice.transitionBegin){
        optionSlice.transitionBegin(transitionState,dispatch)
      }
      if(willLeave){
        dispatch(actions.willLeave(this.state.key))
      }
      else if(willEnter){
        dispatch(actions.willEnter(this.state.key))
      }
      this.setState(merge(this.state,{
        willLeave: willLeave,
        willEnter: willEnter
      }));
      setTimeout(()=>{
        if(optionSlice.transitionComplete){
          optionSlice.transitionEnd(transitionState,dispatch);
        }
        dispatch(actions.transitionComplete(this.state.key))
        this.resetState();
        callback();
      },optionSlice.duration);
    }
    componentWillLeave(callback){
      this.doTransition(callback,options.willLeave,true,false)
    }
    componentWillEnter(callback){
      this.doTransition(callback,options.willEnter,false,true)
    }
    render() {

      console.log(this.props.transitionState);
      console.log(this.state.key);

      var willEnterClasses = options.willEnter.classNames
      var willLeaveClasses = options.willLeave.classNames
      var classes = classnames(
        {[willEnterClasses] : this.state.willEnter},
        {[willLeaveClasses] : this.state.willLeave},
      )
      return <WrappedComponent animationClasses={classes} {...this.props}/>
    }
  }
}
```

***options***

Options have the following structure:

```
{
  willEnter:{
    classNames : "a b c",
    duration: 1000,
    transitionBegin: (state,dispatch) => {//some custom logic.},
    transitionEnd: (state,dispatch) => {//some custom logic.}
         // I currently am not passing anything here, but I hope to make this a library
         // and am adding the feature to cover any use case that may require it.

  },
  willLeave:{
    classNames : "a b c",
    duration: 1000,
    transitionBegin: (state,dispatch) => {//some custom logic.},
    transitionEnd: (state,dispatch) => {//some custom logic.}

  }
}
```

***Transition Lifecycle (onEnter or onLeave)***

- When the component is mounted, `actions.registerComponent` is dispatched

  - `componentWillMount`
- When the component's `componentWillLeave` or `componentWillEnter` hook is called, the corresponding slice of the options is sent to `doTransition`
- In doTransition:

  - The user supplied transitionBegin function is called (`optionSlice.transitionBegin`)
  - The default `action.willLeave` or `action.willEnter` is dispatched
  - A timeout is set for the duration of the animation (`optionSlice.duration`). When the timeout is complete:

    - The user supplied transitionEnd function is called (`optionSlice.transitionEnd`)
    - The default `actions.transitionComplete` is dispatched

Essentially, optionSlice just allows the user to pass in some options. `optionSlice.transitionBegin` and `optionSlice.transitionEnd` are just optional functions that are executed while the animation is going, if that suits a use case. I'm not passing anything in currently for my components, but I hope to make this a library soon, so I'm just covering my bases.

***Why Am I tracking transition states anyway?***

[image]

Depending on the element that is entering, the exiting animation changes, and vice versa.

For example, in the image above, when the blue enters, red moves right, and when the blue exits, red moves left.  However when the green enters, red moves left and when the green exits, red moves right. To control this is why I need to know the state of current transitions.

### **The Problem:**

The `TransitionGroup` contains two elements, one entering, one exiting (controlled by react-router). It passes a prop called `transitionState` to its children. The `Transition` HOC (children of `TransitionGroup`) dispatches certain redux actions through the course of an animation. The `Transition` component that is entering receives the props change as expected, but the component that is exiting is frozen. It's props do not change.

It is always the one that is exiting that does not receive updated props. I have tried switching the wrapped components (exiting and entering), and the issues is not due to the wrapped components.

### **Images**

**On-Screen Transition:**
[image: Transition]

**Transition in React DOM**

[image: Transition2]

The exiting component Transition(Connect(Home))), in this case, is not receiving updated props.

Any ideas why this is the case? Thanks in advance for all the help.

**Update 1:**

```
import React from 'react';
import TransitionGroup from 'react-addons-transition-group';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
var childFactoryMaker = (transitionState,dispatch) => (child) => {
  console.log(child)
  return React.cloneElement(child, {
    key: (child.props.route.path + "//" + child.type.displayName),
    transitionState: transitionState,
    dispatch: dispatch
  })
}

class TransitionContainer extends React.Component{
  render(){
    let{
      transitionState,
      dispatch,
      children
    } = this.props
    return(
      <div>
      <TransitionGroup childFactory={childFactoryMaker(transitionState,dispatch)}>
          {
            children
          }
      </TransitionGroup>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect((state)=>({transitionState:state.transitions}),(dispatch)=>({dispatch:dispatch}))(TransitionContainer)
```

I've updated my `TransitionContainer` to the above. Now, the `componentWillEnter` and `componentWillLeave` hooks are not being called. I logged the `React.cloneElement(child, {...})` in the `childFactory` function, and the hooks (as well as my defined functions like `doTransition`) are present in the `prototype` attribute. Only `constructor`, `componentWillMount` and `componentWillUnmount` are called. I suspect this is because the `key` prop is not being injected through `React.cloneElement`. `transitionState` and `dispatch` are being injected though.

**Update 2:**

```
import React from 'react';
import TransitionGroup from 'react-addons-transition-group';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
var childFactoryMaker = (transitionState,dispatch) => (child) => {
  console.log(React.cloneElement(child, {
    transitionState: transitionState,
    dispatch: dispatch
  }));
  return React.cloneElement(child, {
    key: (child.props.route.path + "//" + child.type.displayName),
    transitionState: transitionState,
    dispatch: dispatch
  })
}

class TransitionContainer extends React.Component{
  render(){
    let{
      transitionState,
      dispatch,
      children
    } = this.props
    return(
      <div>
      <TransitionGroup childFactory={childFactoryMaker(transitionState,dispatch)}>
      {
        React.Children.map(this.props.children,
            (child) => React.cloneElement(child,      //These children are all instances of the Transition HOC
                { key: child.props.route.path + "//" + child.type.displayName}
            )
        )
      }
      </TransitionGroup>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect((state)=>({transitionState:state.transitions}),(dispatch)=>({dispatch:dispatch}))(TransitionContainer)
```

After further inspection of the TransitionGroup source, I realized that I put the key in the wrong place. All is well now. Thanks so much for the help!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Determining Entering and Leaving Children

Imagine rendering the sample JSX below:

```
<TransitionGroup>
  <div key="one">Foo</div>
  <div key="two">Bar</div>
</TransitionGroup>
```

The `<TransitionGroup>`'s `children` prop would be made up of the elements:

```
[
  { type: 'div', props: { key: 'one', children: 'Foo' }},
  { type: 'div', props: { key: 'two', children: 'Bar' }}
]
```

The above elements will be stored as `state.children`. Then,  we update the `<TransitionGroup>` to:

```
<TransitionGroup>
  <div key="two">Bar</div>
  <div key="three">Baz</div>
</TransitionGroup>
```

When `componentWillReceiveProps` is called, its `nextProps.children` will be:

```
[
  { type: 'div', props: { key: 'two', children: 'Bar' }},
  { type: 'div', props: { key: 'three', children: 'Baz' }}
]
```

Comparing `state.children` and `nextProps.children`, we can determine that:

1.
`{ type: 'div', props: { key: 'one', children: 'Foo' }}` is leaving

2.
`{ type: 'div', props: { key: 'three', children: 'Baz' }}` is entering.

In a regular React application, this means that `<div>Foo</div>` would no longer be rendered, but that is not the case for the children of a `<TransitionGroup>`.

#### How `<TransitionGroup>` Works

So how exactly is `<TransitionGroup>` able to continue rendering components that no longer exist in `props.children`?

What `<TransitionGroup>` does is that it maintains a `children` array in its state. Whenever the `<TransitionGroup>` receives new props, this array is updated by [merging](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/master/src/TransitionGroup.js#L47-L55) the current `state.children` and the `nextProps.children`. (The initial array is created in the `constructor` using the initial `children` prop).

Now, when the `<TransitionGroup>` renders, it renders every child in the `state.children` array. After it has rendered, it calls `performEnter` and `performLeave` on any entering or leaving children. This in turn will perform the transitioning methods of the components.

After a leaving component's `componentWillLeave` method (if it has one) has finished executing, it will remove itself from the `state.children` array so that it no longer renders (assuming it didn't re-enter while it was leaving).

#### Passing Props to Leaving Children?

Now the question is, why aren't updated props being passed to the leaving element? Well, how would it receive props? Props are passed from a parent component to a child component. If you look at the example JSX above, you can see that the leaving element is in a detached state. It has no parent and it is only rendered because the `<TransitionGroup>` is storing it in its `state`.

When you are attempting to inject the state to the children of your `<TransitionGroup>` through `React.cloneElement`, the leaving component is not one of those children.

#### The Good News

You can pass a `childFactory` prop to your `<TransitionGroup>`. The default `childFactory` just returns the child, but you can take a look at the `<CSSTransitionGroup>` for a more [advanced child factory](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/master/src/CSSTransitionGroup.js#L31-L45).

You can inject the correct props into the children (even the leaving ones) through this child wrapper.

```
function childFactory(child) {
  return React.cloneElement(child, {
    transitionState,
    dispatch
  })
}
```

Usage:

```
var ConnectedTransitionGroup = connect(
  store => ({
   transitionState: state.transitions
  }),
  dispatch => ({ dispatch })
)(TransitionGroup)

render() {
  return (
    <ConnectedTransitionGroup childFactory={childFactory}>
      {children}
    </ConnectedTransitionGroup>
  )
}
```

React Transition Group was somewhat recently split out of the main React repo and you can view its source code [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group). It is pretty straightforward to read through.

Comment: Since I need to access the state in the `Transition` HOC, I would naturally wrap it in connect(). However, the problem then is that `TransitionGroup` will stop working, as the connect-ed Transition HOC's now do not implement the `componentWillLeave` and `componentWillEnter` hooks. Or am I not seeing something? Thanks for all the help by the way @Paul S.

Comment: That does complicate things. What are the transition states that you are sending to your transitioning components?

Comment: Its just which elements are leaving/entering. Something like `{home: "willLeave", bom: "willEnter", otherPage1:"transitionComplete"` The reason I do this is so that I can dynamically change the transition based on which route is being taken. @PaulS

Comment: Is that related to your `optionSlice.transitionBegin` function? I don't think that I am fully understanding the need here tracking which components are transitioing in Redux. Can the transition for one component vary based on which other components are also transitioning?

Comment: No, and yes. `optionSlice.transitionBegin` and `optionSlice.transitionEnd`is just an optional function that can be passed in to be executed during the animation. But you are correct in that the reason im tracking the transition components is that the transition can change based on which component is entering. So really, all I need to know is which component[s] are entering.  Please see my edit. I hope that will bring some clarity. @Paul S.

Comment: Edited my post with slightly more detail (see the "The Good News" section), but I think that you should pass a `childFactory` prop to your transition group to inject props into all of the children.

Comment: Key is not being sent for some reason, and the `componentWillEnter` and `componentWillLeave` hooks are not being called (and the animation is not being executed). Please see my update @Paul S.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the inner workings of TransitionGroup so thoroughly @Paul S. I am new to React and the documentation on React Transition Group is very brief so I've been struggling to get my head around it. I have a question about cancelling the transition effect of a leaving/entering child. I'm not sure if `childFactory` would be useful in this case but I was wondering if you could please take a look at the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64888240/10841085)? I have tried using the `onEnter` callback and on `enter` prop to no avail.

Comment: I've tried using `childFactory` in [my example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-stateful-p4fee?file=/src/styles.css) and it's almost yielding the result that I am after except that it does not update the timeout of all leaving children. To illustrate, when you click Next on app launch, the transition from child First to child Second begins. If you click Next again before the transition has ended, the timeout of child First does not update. I'm not sure I understand why.