# React-transition-group dynamic exit animation for SwitchTransition

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-transition-group

I'm trying to make an app with a dynamic exit animation. Exit animation for SwitchTransition is set when the component is rendered and can't be changed later. It can be achieved using childFactory and TransitionGroup [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404232/react-transitiongroup-and-react-cloneelement-do-not-send-updated-props), but in this way the animation happens simultaneously. I need to make react wait until previous is unmounted - like in SwitchTransition. So the question: is it possible to have something like childFactory for SwitchTransition or make TransitionGroup behave the same way as SwitchTransition mode 'out-in'. Thanks in advance!

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(true);
  const [direction, setDirection] = React.useState("left");
  return (
      <div className="main">
        <SwitchTransition mode="out-in">
          <CSSTransition
            key={state}
            addEndListener={(node, done) => {
              node.addEventListener("transitionend", done, false);
            }}
            classNames={direction === "left" ? "fade--left" : "fade--right"}
          >
            <div className="button-container">
              <Button
                onClick={() => {
                  setState((state) => !state);
                  const dir = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "right" : "left";
                  setDirection(dir);
                }}
              >
                {direction}
              </Button>
            </div>
          </CSSTransition>
        </SwitchTransition>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: For anyone looking for something similar, maybe this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72392261/4774045) can help.