# There's some way to add fadein or slide effect on "react-dates-range" when i change between months?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm using the library **https://github.com/hypeserver/react-date-range** , `react 17.0.2` and `next 12.0.0`

I would like that when I change from one month to another, instead of making a sudden change, to be able to configure a Fade-In, or a Slide, just as it happens in the AirBnb calendar.

Does anyone know how I can do this? Thank you very much and sorry for the inconvenience.

This is my actual behavior

[image]

This is something like what I want, but it could also be a fade in or something similar.

[image]

Comment: There is component of this date range `react-dates` [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/dlf47?file=/src/index.js) and [link](https://github.com/react-dates/react-dates). Not sure this will fulfil your requirements like `react-date-range`

Comment: Thanks usama, i was tried with these library, but only works on react <= 16.8 and a i used 17.0.1v

Comment: If you having issue installing then use this command `npm i react-dates --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good practice, anyway moment js is a dependency and it also has issues with react 17. On the other hand this library is not updated for 2 years. Thank you very much, this library brings this behavior by default, but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly like Airbnb i believe its not possible because the `react-date-range` works a little different from what airbnb does.

But you can get similar behavior using `SwitchTransition` and `CSSTransition`  from `react-transition-group` library. You can check their docs [here](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/).

First, here's the [code sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-daterangerpick-with-transition-ggljcf) with `DateRangerPicker` using `CSSTransition` between months.

And below the same code, with comments on what its doing:

**CSS file:**

```css
/*
Overflow the Calendar container 
.rdrDateRangeWrapper is a class that react-date-range creates internally
*/
.rdrDateRangeWrapper {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

/*
.rdrMonths is the class that react-date-range creates internally for the month container calendar

.fadeRightToLeft classes is related to react-transition-group
Created for transition from right to left
*/
.fadeRightToLeft-enter .rdrMonths {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
.fadeRightToLeft-enter-active .rdrMonths {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.fadeRightToLeft-exit .rdrMonths {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.fadeRightToLeft-exit-active .rdrMonths {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.fadeRightToLeft-enter-active .rdrMonths,
.fadeRightToLeft-exit-active .rdrMonths {
  transition: opacity 100ms, transform 100ms;
}

/*
Same as fadeRightToLeft:
.fadeLeftToRight classes is related to react-transition-group
Created for transition from left to right
*/
.fadeLeftToRight-enter .rdrMonths {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.fadeLeftToRight-enter-active .rdrMonths {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.fadeLeftToRight-exit .rdrMonths {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.fadeLeftToRight-exit-active .rdrMonths {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
.fadeLeftToRight-enter-active .rdrMonths,
.fadeLeftToRight-exit-active .rdrMonths {
  transition: opacity 100ms, transform 100ms;
}
```

**Component file:**

```jsx
import { useState } from "react";
import { addDays, isAfter } from "date-fns";
import { DateRangePicker } from "react-date-range";
import { SwitchTransition, CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";

import "react-date-range/dist/styles.css";
import "react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([
    {
      startDate: new Date(),
      endDate: addDays(new Date(), 7),
      key: "selection"
    }
  ]);

  // state created to hold the first month that calendar is showing
  const [shownDateChangeValue, setShownDateChangeValue] = useState(new Date());

  // state created to check if use created next Month ou previous month
  const [isNextMonth, setIsNextMonth] = useState(true);

  return (
    <SwitchTransition mode="out-in">
      <CSSTransition
        /*** call the transition when month changes ***/
        key={shownDateChangeValue}
        /*** code related to SwitchTransition ***/
        addEndListener={(node, done) =>
          node.addEventListener("transitionend", done, false)
        }
        /*** Set the transition class related to the user action ***/
        classNames={isNextMonth ? "fadeRightToLeft" : "fadeLeftToRight"}
      >
        <DateRangePicker
          onChange={(item) => {
            setState([item.selection]);
          }}
          showSelectionPreview={true}
          moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}
          months={2}
          ranges={state}
          direction="horizontal"
          /*** set the current month ***/
          shownDate={shownDateChangeValue}
          /*** Change shownDateChangeValue and isNextMonth states, dispatching the transition ***/
          onShownDateChange={(month) => {
            /* check if user click next or previous month */
            const isNext = isAfter(month, shownDateChangeValue);

            setIsNextMonth(isNext ? true : false);

            setShownDateChangeValue(month);
          }}
        />
      </CSSTransition>
    </SwitchTransition>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you click next and then click prev, the first click for prev button displays the exit animation from next and enter from prev. To fix this TransitionGroup childFactory has to be used.